# GNN with Stable baselines

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines, pytorch-geometric, dgl

I am looking to use [DGL](https://www.dgl.ai/) or pytorch geometric for building my policy and value networks in stable baselines, however I am struggling to figure out how to send over observations.  The observations must be one of the gym `spaces` class but I am not sure how to send a graph object that can be used by DGL or Pytorch geometric in this way.

The fundamental question I have is how to send graph observations and where to do the prepossessing necessary to use DGL or pytorch geometric for a custom stable baselines network?  Can I pack the graph into a stable baselines observation space that somehow DGL or pytorch geometric could intake it?

Note: If anyone has a github link with any code that has done this please let me know, I have looked everywhere

Comment: Can your graph be represented with a fixed size representation? Like do the number of nodes change and is the node count equal for all instances of your environment?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize your DGL graph object using pickle and convert the resultant byte string into a vector of integers (with each char in the string corresponding to one int).

```
import dgl
import numpy as np
import pickle

def serialize_graph(graph: dgl.DGLGraph):
    as_byte_string = pickle.dumps(graph)
    as_int_list = [_ for _ in as_byte_string]  # we get ints for free without explicitly casting
    as_float_array = np.array(as_int_list, dtype=np.float32)
    return as_float_array
```

You can then apply the same operations in reverse to deserialize vector representation of the graph within your custom feature extractor.

```
import dgl
import pickle
import torch as th

def deserialize_graph(observation: th.Tensor):
    as_int_tensor = observation.to(dtype=th.int32)
    as_char_list = [chr(_) for _ in observation]
    as_byte_string = bytearray(''.join(as_char_list), encoding='latin')
    as_dgl_graph = pickle.loads(as_byte_string)
    return as_dgl_graph
```

Comment: Can you handle dynamic graph size with this approach? And which type of [space](https://github.com/openai/gym/tree/master/gym/spaces) do you suggest?